# Issue with displaying login dialog in facebook sdk 3.1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using facebook sdk 3.1 for my ios app. I want to show login dialog something similar to this

[image]

It is working fine for ios 5 devices. But for ios 6, Its showing only an alertView instead of facebook app login page.

This is my code

```
- (void)openSession
{
NSArray *permissions =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_location", @"user_birthday", nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
```

}

How can I always show facebook app login dialog instead of default alertView?

Comment: What alert are you getting? can you write here ? I had some problem like this if you write the alert it will helpful for both of us to understand.

Comment: It is just an UIAlertView with message "**myAppName** would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends" AND the Alert title is "Facebook"

Comment: Can you show the alert ?